# concept std::derived_from when the argument is a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a few functions like so

```
bool RegisterModel (std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> model) { }

bool RegisterModel (std::shared_ptr<DerivedB> model) { }
```

and i would like to make use of c++ 20 concepts and implement it like this:

```
bool RegisterModel (std::derived_from<BaseClass> auto model) { }
```

This does not work, because i'm passing in shared pointers. It is somehow possible to require a shared pointer that holds an object derived from `BaseClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deduce the `T` from a `std::shared_ptr<T>` and constrain that:

```cpp
template<std::derived_from<BaseClass> T>
bool RegisterModel (std::shared_ptr<T> model) { }

// Or as an abbreviated function template
bool RegisterModel (std::shared_ptr<std::derived_from<BaseClass> auto> model) { }
```

Comment: Well, i'm not sure how i didn't figure it out myself, now that i can see the example. I feel dumb :D Works perfectly, thank you!